# Как вставить код капчи в send.php?

Tags: php, phpmailer, recaptcha, формы

У меня есть рабочий код капчи и PHPMailer.

send.php с PHPMailer выглядит так:

```html
<?php
// Файлы phpmailer
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';

// Переменные, которые отправляет пользователь
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$file = $_FILES['myfile'];

// Формирование самого письма
$title = "Заголовок письма";
$body = "
<h2>Новое письмо</h2>
<b>Имя:</b> $name<br>
<b>Почта:</b> $email<br><br>
<b>Сообщение:</b><br>$text
";

// Настройки PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
try {
    $mail->isSMTP();   
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {$GLOBALS['status'][] = $str;};

    // Настройки вашей почты
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.yandex.ru'; // SMTP сервера вашей почты
    $mail->Username   = 'yandex'; // Логин на почте
    $mail->Password   = '*******'; // Пароль на почте
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->setFrom('yandex@yandex.ru', 'Заявка с сайта!'); // Адрес самой почты и имя отправителя

    // Получатель письма
    $mail->addAddress('google@gmail.com');  

    // Прикрипление файлов к письму
if (!empty($file['name'][0])) {
    for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($file['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($file['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $file['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
            $rfile[] = "Файл $filename прикреплён";
        } else {
            $rfile[] = "Не удалось прикрепить файл $filename";
        }
    }   
}

// Отправка сообщения
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $title;
$mail->Body = $body;    

// Проверяем отравленность сообщения
if ($mail->send()) {$result = "success";} 
else {$result = "error";}

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = "error";
    $status = "Сообщение не было отправлено. Причина ошибки: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

// Отображение результата
echo json_encode(["result" => $result, "resultfile" => $rfile, "status" => $status]);
?>
```

Код капчи выглядит так:

```html
<?php
$captcha;
if(isset($_POST['token'])){
  $captcha=$_POST['token'];
}

$secretKey = "********************";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// post request to server

$url =  'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secretKey .  '&response=' . $_POST['token'];
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
header('Content-type: application/json');
if($responseKeys["success"] && $responseKeys["score"] >= 0.5) {
  echo json_encode(array('success' => 'true', 'om_score' => $responseKeys["score"], 'token' => $_POST['token']));
} else {
  echo json_encode(array('success' => 'false', 'om_score' => $responseKeys["score"], 'token' => $_POST['token']));
}
?>
```

Как объединить код капчи с PHPmailer? То есть как вставить код капчи в send.php с PHPmailer? Пробовал просто вставлять, но тогда форма перестает работать.